# Map "syntax error before " (first element) while URI.encode_query(form)

Tags: maps, elixir

I've been doing [this](https://github.com/Besatnias/code-dumpster/blob/master/tex.ex) for a couple of days, and I'm having this problem:

Whenever I try to encode a map into query string, I get the error "syntax error before: chat_id"

```
form = %{
      "chat_id" => 237799109,
      "text" => "OMG a message"
    }

{status, body} = URI.encode_query(form)

#=> (SyntaxError) lib/elixir.ex:20: syntax error before: chat_id
```

But as far as I know this is the map syntax, isn't it? As seen [here](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/URI.html#encode_query/1), where this example is presented:

```
iex> hd = %{"foo" => 1, "bar" => 2}
iex> URI.encode_query(hd)
"bar=2&foo=1
```

What is happening here?

Full error message:

```
== Compilation error on file lib/elixir.ex ==
** (SyntaxError) lib/elixir.ex:20: syntax error before: chat_id
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:117: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.Paral
lelCompiler.spawn_compilers/1
```

Comment: Well, it works in IEx........... I have no idea where the error lies then.

Comment: In the file you linked to, you have a space after `def req` which isn't allowed in Elixir (but the error message is not the same as you posted here). After I remove the space, the file compiles (with some warnings, but no error).

Comment: Uhh, I removed the space and still got the same error, "syntax error before: chat_id", and also the warning "an expression is always required on the right side of ->" edit: maybe it is my version of elixir? nah it's 1.4.0, latest is just 1.4.2

Comment: How are you running the code? That file contains some invalid code (`@moduledoc` outside a module). Can you post the exact code that can be run with `elixir foo.exs`?

Comment: I use iex -S mix on Windows cmd. I used moduledoc to make a comment, but I can paste it inside the module. Also, I've never dealt with .exs, so I don't know. Edit: I put @moduledoc inside the module (same result of course)

Comment: As far as I can see, there are no syntax errors in the code you have on Github right now. This doesn't throw any error: `File.read!("tex.ex") |> Code.string_to_quoted`.

Comment: I just noticed that the code is creating a new file called `OMG a message}`. No, it created it a while ago, but new compilations attempts don't lead to file creation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138419/discussion-between-besto-and-dogbert).

Comment: I just copied it to another folder, changed the mix.exs to only include the dependencies I was going to use (in this case only Poison and HTTPoison) and it compiled perfectly... Still no idea what caused this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you would get the error you listed, but `URI.encode_query/1` only returns a single `binary` argument. You are trying to pattern match it against a `tuple`.

Can you paste more of the code instead of just those 2 lines?

```
iex(2)> URI.encode_query(form)
"chat_id=237&text=OMG+a+message"
```

Comment: That is what I was doing. I think it was a problem in other files, not that specific file.